# Memory microsoft visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

when I use diagnostics tool I can see that the process memory is going to 25 MB, can I extend this and let the MVS 2015 take more memory? I am having some issues and even though I don't get any errors my application suddenly stops (I use recurssion, sorry VS).

Answer (score 0):

There is no indication in your question that Visual Studio needs more memory.

If your app uses recursion, you might be running out of stack space; this condition, ironically, is called "stack overflow" :) You can specify (via the linker option) that you require more stack space, the default is 1 MB. However, I would rather review the algorithn, as this "fix" may only put your problem further away.